# Unlock An Oracle Table

Tags: mysql, oracle, session, locking

What are the different techniques for Unlocking an oracle table?

What I Tried.

1. Get the object ID of the locked table:

   > SELECT object_id FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name='YOUR TABLE NAME';
2. Get the SID values for this ID:

   > SELECT sid FROM v$lock WHERE id1=OBJECT ID FROM STEP1
3. Get the session values for these SIDs:

   > SELECT sid, serial# from v$session where sid in (COMMA SEPARATED LIST OF SIDs FROM STEP2.)
4. Kill the sessions causing the lock:

   > ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION (SID,SERIAL#)

pair values from step 3
e.g. `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '231,23454'`

But The Problem is I have lot of tables which has been locked is there any other technique for unlocking the tables.

I am using SQLDeveloper Is there any direct option for unlocking it.

Comment: related on DBA: [Tracing, debugging and fixing Row Lock Contentions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/tracing-debugging-and-fixing-row-lock-contentions)

Comment: Why would you want to unlock tables? Transaction locks on rows are fine, they protect you against corruptions. If locks are on tables you can better check why they are on TABLE. Locks can be a problem but only when they are blocking and when they last long. App design is the first thing to check in case of problems,

Comment: @ik_zelf, Yes you are correct but I want to unlock the tables because I am not able to do any operations and not even able to check why those tables are getting locked.

Comment: What you are doing is dangerous, just FYI. You are setting yourself up for data corruption. If your application is locking rows for update and not unlocking them you need to bring the application down and figure out why, not unlock the rows and allow people to get back to work.

Comment: @mmmmmpie, Thaks but this is not live environment this just a test environment, And I am not able to figure out the cause of getting lock so untill I unlock the tables I cant debug also.

Comment: I guess unlocking the table is not primary thing you need to focus on. Try to find out why it has locked by recreating the scenario.

Answer (score 13):

**Option 1:**

Well, one of the options is to rollback the locked SQL statement. For an instance,

```
lock table table1 in exclusive mode;  -- is what you should've used to lock the table.
```

To unlock: rollback;

**Option 2:**

To find username and sid:

```
select * from v$locked_object;
```

To find serial# using sid:

```
select * from v$session where sid= put the sid you found on v$locked_object;
```

To kill session:

```
alter system kill session 'sid, serial#'; -- Execute this command as sysdba as normal user won't have privilege.
```

Comment: Does oracle autounlock an object after some time ?

Answer (score 4):

You can also try to execute just

```
COMMIT;
```

or

```
ROLLBACK;
```

in this session.

Comment: commit work because i'm the one locking the table, forgot to commit

Answer (score 0):

**1. To find serial#,sid:**

```
select
   c.owner,
   c.object_name,
   c.object_type,
   b.sid,
   b.serial#,
   b.status,
   b.osuser,
   b.machine
from
   v$locked_object a ,
   v$session b,
   dba_objects c
where
   b.sid = a.session_id
and
   a.object_id = c.object_id;
```

**2. To kill session:**

```
alter system kill session 'sid, serial#';
```